# How to filter by child object property with QuerydslPredicate?

Tags: java, h2, querydsl

I have a "Pet" domain and a "Person" domain, a person may have a pet. Using QuerydslPredicate on my RestController, I would like to return only the persons that have a Pet of type "DOG".

Pet.java

```java
@Entity
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "animal_type")
    private AnimalType type;

    // constructors & getters/setters
}


enum AnimalType {
    DOG, CAT
}
```

Person.java

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String surname;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id")
    private Pet pet;

    // constructors & getters/setters
}
```

PersonController.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("persons")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> getAll(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Person.class) Predicate predicate)
    {
        return (List<Person>) personRepository.findAll(predicate);
    }
}
```

PersonRepository.java

```java
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person> {
}
```

I'd like to query only persons that have a dog with a GET request like this:

```java
localhost:8080/persons?pet.type=DOG
```

But this renders the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-09T18:11:23.430+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not access method: Class org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils can not access a member of class com.example.demo.domain.QPerson with modifiers \"protected\"",
    "path": "/persons"
}
```

Querying for people named "Tom" works fine though using `localhost:8080/persons?name=Tom`.

I have this repo available [here](https://bitbucket.org/rafaoliveira/querydsl/src/master/).

I have already tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927280/spring-querydsl-predicate-relationship-support), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385036/querydsl-generated-classes-not-able-to-access-second-level-elements-for-querying?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918824/spring-querydslpredicate-questions/41117723), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898781/querydslpredicate-throwing-exception/50898963) stackoverflow questions, but haven't being able to make it work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `querydsl.entityAccessors` property in your `pom.xml` to `false` (or remove it, the default value is `false`).

**Why this is happening?**

In your `pom.xml`, you have the following configuration:

```
<querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
```

This option makes your relationships being created as `protected` methods in your class, hence your error (https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/master/querydsl-codegen/src/main/java/com/querydsl/codegen/EntitySerializer.java#L211).

```
if (config.useEntityAccessors()) {
    writer.protectedField(queryType, field.getEscapedName());
} else {
    writer.publicFinal(queryType, field.getEscapedName());
}
```